# Erroneous nesting of equation structure & Extra }

Tags: mathtools

I do not know what is wrong with my code I serve the web but could not find why I am having lots of errors in this small code. Please someone help

```
  \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\let\pi\uppi
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{align*}
        \begin{split}
            & \mathcal{P}\left( \left. \frac{1}{a_{n}}\smashoperator[l]{\sum_{i=1}^{n}}\left( X_{i}-\mu _{0}\right) \omega _{i} \\
            &\qquad \leq \frac{1}{a_{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( X_{i}-\mu _{0}\right) \\ &\vert \{ \left\vert X_{i}-\mu _{0}\right\vert \} _{1}^{n} \biggr)   
        \end{split}
    \end{align*}
\end{equation}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, the error is nesting `align*` and `equation`

Comment: Furthermore, you have an unmatched `\left(` at the beginning of the equation. As far as I know, you can't span these across `&` or `\\ `. Try `\Bigg(` instead.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you very much so you mean I should not use align* and equation? I am new to latex so please give me more supportive answers.

Comment: @wrtlprnft Thank you so I should not use the function \left when I have an &

Comment: @rsc05: Yes, never use `equation` and `align` in nesting. If you need more than one equation use `align` (or `align*` etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version that compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\let\pi\uppi
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            &\mathcal{P}\Biggl(\frac{1}{a_{n}}\smashoperator[l]{\sum_{i=1}^{n}}\left( X_{i}-\mu _{0}\right) \omega _{i} \\
            &\qquad \leq \frac{1}{a_{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( X_{i}-\mu _{0}\right) \\
            &\qquad\bigg\vert \{ \left\vert X_{i}-\mu _{0}\right\vert \} _{1}^{n} \Biggr)
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of formula]

This is what I changed:

- the `\begin{align*}` is unnecessary since `\begin{equation*}` is already a display math environment and you're using `\begin{spit}` to do the multi-line display
- the `\left(` in the first line is missing its counterpart. Since these large operators don't work across columns or rows, I replaced them with `\Bigg` versions
- I enlarged the size of the `\vert` and added space in front of it.